# Dual norm - Equivalent definitions - Brezis.

Tags: functional-analysis

In Brezis, it defines the dual norm by:

$ \sup_{\|x\|\leq 1} f(x) = \sup_{\|x\|\leq 1} |f(x)|  $

I should prove that:

1. $ \sup_{\|x\|\leq 1} f(x) \leq \sup_{\|x\|\leq 1} |f(x)|  $
2. $ \sup_{\|x\|\leq 1} |f(x)| \leq \sup_{\|x\|\leq 1} f(x) $

Proof:

1) By definition of the supremum:

$ f(x) \leq |f(x)| \leq \sup_{\|x\|\leq 1} |f(x)| \quad \forall x \in X, \; \|x\| \leq 1 $

Then:

$ \sup_{\|x\|\leq 1} f(x) \leq \sup_{\|x\|\leq 1} |f(x)| $

2) My idea to prove this part is use that:

$ A, B \neq \emptyset \; \text{and bounded}, \quad A \subset B \quad \text{then} \quad \sup A \leq \sup B$

How define A and B, to obtain  $ \sup_{\|x\|\leq 1} |f(x)| \leq \sup_{\|x\|\leq 1} f(x) $ ?

Comment: If $f(x)$ is coming out too negatively, try $f(-x)$ instead.

Answer (score 2):

Let $x_n$ such that $\|x_n\| \le 1$ such that
$$|f(x_n)| \to \sup_{\|x\| \le 1} |f(x)|.$$
Then, let
$$y_n = \operatorname{sign}(f(x_n)) x_n.$$
We have
$$\|y_n\| = |\operatorname{sign}(f(x_n))| \cdot \|x_n\| = \|x_n\| \le 1,$$
and
$$f(y_n) = \operatorname{sign}(f(x_n)) f(x_n) = |f(x_n)| \to \sup_{\|x\| \le 1} |f(x)|.$$
Therefore,
$$\sup_{\|x\| \le 1} |f(x)| \le \sup_{\|x\| \le 1} f(x).$$

Answer (score 0):

For any $x$ note that $|f(x)|=f(x)$ or $|f(x)|=f(-x)$. If $\|x\| \leq 1$ then $\|-x\|\leq 1$ too so $|f(x)| \leq \sup_{\{\|x\|\leq 1\}} f(x)$ in both cases. Now take supremum over $x$ with $\|x\| \leq 1$.